# Element-wise max operation on sparse matrices in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to take an element-wise maximum of two matrices of class "Matrix" (sparse matrices).  I've tried the `pmax(...)` function, which seems to work on two 'normal' matrices, but when I pass in two sparse matrices, it gives me the following error on R 2.15.

```
library(Matrix)
# Loading required package: lattice
v=Matrix(0,100,100); v[1,1]=1; 
x=v
pmax(v,x)
# Error in pmax(v, x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
# In addition: Warning message:
# In any(nas) : coercing argument of type 'list' to logical
```

Comment: Just to check: doing `as.matrix(v)` isn't an option because it's a large, sparse matrix?

Comment: Also, how large/how sparse are we talking?

Comment: too large to convert to a standard matrix -- it's 100,000 by 100,000

Answer (score 8):

As you discovered `pmax` doesn't support sparse matrices. The reason is because `cbind` doesn't support the sparse matrices. The author of `Matrix` has written `cBind` which is the equivalent of `cbind`. If you change one line in the `pmax` function, it works correctly:

```
pmax.sparse=function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    elts <- list(...)
    if (length(elts) == 0L) 
        stop("no arguments")
    if (all(vapply(elts, function(x) is.atomic(x) && !is.object(x), 
        NA))) {
        mmm <- .Internal(pmax(na.rm, ...))
    }
    else {
        mmm <- elts[[1L]]
        attr(mmm, "dim") <- NULL
        has.na <- FALSE
        for (each in elts[-1L]) {
            attr(each, "dim") <- NULL
            l1 <- length(each)
            l2 <- length(mmm)
            if (l2 < l1) {
                if (l2 && l1%%l2) 
                  warning("an argument will be fractionally recycled")
                mmm <- rep(mmm, length.out = l1)
            }
            else if (l1 && l1 < l2) {
                if (l2%%l1) 
                  warning("an argument will be fractionally recycled")
                each <- rep(each, length.out = l2)
            }
            # nas <- cbind(is.na(mmm), is.na(each))
            nas <- cBind(is.na(mmm), is.na(each)) # Changed row.
            if (has.na || (has.na <- any(nas))) {
                mmm[nas[, 1L]] <- each[nas[, 1L]]
                each[nas[, 2L]] <- mmm[nas[, 2L]]
            }
            change <- mmm < each
            change <- change & !is.na(change)
            mmm[change] <- each[change]
            if (has.na && !na.rm) 
                mmm[nas[, 1L] | nas[, 2L]] <- NA
        }
    }
    mostattributes(mmm) <- attributes(elts[[1L]])
    mmm
}

pmax.sparse(x,v)
# Works fine.
```

Comment: When I test your method on large sparse matrices, I get `Cholmod error 'problem too large'`. Even with a smaller problem, I get `<sparse>[ <logic> ] : .M.sub.i.logical() maybe inefficient` warnings and the output is not the expected `pmax`. Any idea?

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. As you noted, the function does not work. The first problem is that the `!` operator turns the sparse matrix into a dense matrix, by converting all empty cells to `FALSE`. I fixed this problem, but the next problem is that efficient indexing (by another sparse matrix of `logical`) has not been implemented in the package. It seems like it would be an easy fix, not that I have given it a try.

Answer (score 7):

Try this. It concatenates the matrices `summary` outputs, then takes the max after grouping by `(i, j)` pairs. It is also generalizable in the sense you can do any type of element-wise operation, just replace `max` with the function of your choice (or write a general function that takes a `FUN` argument).

```
pmax.sparse <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) {

   # check that all matrices have conforming sizes
   num.rows <- unique(sapply(list(...), nrow))
   num.cols <- unique(sapply(list(...), ncol))
   stopifnot(length(num.rows) == 1)
   stopifnot(length(num.cols) == 1)

   cat.summary <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(...), summary))
   out.summary <- aggregate(x ~ i + j, data = cat.summary, max, na.rm)

   sparseMatrix(i = out.summary$i,
                j = out.summary$j,
                x = out.summary$x,
                dims = c(num.rows, num.cols))
}
```

If your matrices are so big and not sparse enough that this code is too slow for your need, I would consider a similar approach using `data.table`.

Here is an application example:

```
N <- 1000000
n <- 10000
M1 <- sparseMatrix(i = sample(N,n), j = sample(N,n), x = runif(n), dims = c(N,N))
M2 <- sparseMatrix(i = sample(N,n), j = sample(N,n), x = runif(n), dims = c(N,N))
M3 <- sparseMatrix(i = sample(N,n), j = sample(N,n), x = runif(n), dims = c(N,N))
system.time(p <- pmax.sparse(M1,M2,M3))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.58    0.06    2.65
```

The other proposed solution fails with:

```
Error in .class1(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 106
```

Answer (score 1):

Modification to flodel's answer (can not comment the answer directly) to speed up calculations on larger matrices by using data.table package.

Run using original, flodel's, version:

```
> object.size(m1)
# 131053304 bytes
> dim(m1)
# [1] 8031286      39
> object.size(m2)
# 131053304 bytes
> dim(m2)
# [1] 8031286      39
> system.time(pmax.sparse(m1, m2))
# user  system elapsed 
# 326.253  21.805 347.969
```

Modifying calculation of cat.summary, out.summary and resulting matrix to:

```
cat.summary <- rbindlist(lapply(list(...), summary)) # that's data.table
out.summary <- cat.summary[, list(x = max(x)), by = c("i", "j")]

sparseMatrix(i = out.summary[,i],
             j = out.summary[,j],
             x = out.summary[,x],
             dims = c(num.rows, num.cols))
```

Run modified version:

```
> system.time(pmax.sparse(m1, m2))
# user  system elapsed 
# 21.546   0.049  21.589
```